# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting using the platform module

Tags: python, string, platform

```
import platform, urllib2

ip = urllib2.urlopen("http://whatismyip.org").read()
os = str(platform.win32_ver()[0])
os2 = str(platform.win32_ver()[1])
os3 = str(platform.win32_ver()[2])
arch = str(platform.machine())
processor = str(platform.processor())

print """
            System data collector
===============================================================
Operating system: $s ($s [%s])
Architecture: %s
Processor: %s

Public IP Address: %s
""" % (os, os2, os3, arch, processor, ip)
```

That code throws a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` when run. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: You got a typo there that is causing the issue. It's `%s`, not `$s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
Operating system: $s ($s [%s])
```

should be

```
Operating system: %s (%s [%s])
```

Comment: Ugh... silly me. That mistake is kinda embarrassing. I've been using PHP a lot lately so I've been using the dollar sign :P